# Unable to integrate Rasa chatbot with Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, chatbot, ngrok, rasa

I have developed a chatbot in Rasa and I want to integrate it to Telegram. My chatbot works great locally, I have run test and I am ready to publish it. However when I tried to integrate it with Telegram it seems that it doesn't work.

In credentials.yml I have the following code:

```
telegram:
  access_token: <Token provided by the Botfather>
  verify: My_BOT
  webhook_url: "https:/url.ngrok.io/webhooks/telegram/webhook"
```

As you can see I am using ngrok for the webhook url. When I paste the ngrok url in my browser with the Rasa server running, I get the message "Hello from Rasa 2.8.2", an indicator that it should work, but when I try to interact with my bot on Telegram it does nothing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you set up the telegram bot as described https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/telegram? And are there any logs from your running Rasa server? It would help to start it with the `--debug` flag to see if the telegram endpoint is listed properly on startup

Comment: I realized that it's my Telegram account it doesnt work with. I tested it with 3 other Telegram accounts and it seems to work there.